# ¿Cómo evitar que una validación (DataAnnotations) salga repetida si se falla en otro campo validad?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Lo que sucede es que si fallo en uno o más campos validados, se muestran en todos los demás, necesito que sólo se muestre en el que ocurrió el error.

[image: Lo que quiero cambiar]

Comment: Hola  @masavi podrías publicar tu código para que sea más fácil para la comunidad apoyarte a resolver tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Sin el código de la vista tendría que adivinar, pero problablemente estás usando `@Html.ValidationSummary` en cada campo y debes usar `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TuCampo)`. El primero muestra todos los mensajes de error del modelo, el segundo es para el campo específico que le pases como parámetro.